# Calculating the difference between dates with certain parameters from data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, data-science

I am interested in calculating the time difference (in days) of time between orders from the same provider

Source data frame:

| OrderNumber | CatID | CustomerID | CreateDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6543 | 4901 | 1111 | 2008-01-01 |
| 6543 | 4901 | 2222 | 2008-01-03 |
| 1113 | 4910 | 3333 | 2008-01-03 |
| 1234 | 5436 | 1111 | 2008-01-05 |
| 1245 | 6434 | 2222 | 2008-01-10 |
| 1456 | 2453 | 1111 | 2008-01-12 |
| 1567 | 64355 | 3333 | 2008-01-13 |

The `OrderNumber` and `CatID` are not interesting.

I want to calc the difference between date in same customerID.

Target DateFrame:

| OrderNumber | CatID | CustomerID | CreateDate | calc days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6543 | 4901 | 1111 | 2008-01-01 | 4 days |
| 6543 | 4901 | 2222 | 2008-01-03 | 7 days |
| 1113 | 4910 | 3333 | 2008-01-03 | 10 days |
| 1234 | 5436 | 1111 | 2008-01-05 | 7 days |
| 1245 | 6434 | 2222 | 2008-01-10 | 5 days |
| 1456 | 2453 | 1111 | 2008-01-12 | 1 days |
| 1567 | 64355 | 3333 | 2008-01-13 | - |
| 6436 | 64355 | 1111 | 2008-01-13 | - |
| 1253 | 64355 | 2222 | 2008-01-15 | - |

*the OrderNumber and  CatID not interesting*

Original data

```
       OrderNumber  CustomerID CreateDate
------------------------------------------
0            27986   712841200 2008-01-01
1            28917   712841200 2008-04-16
2            28451   712630100 2008-02-27
3            29836   712630100 2008-08-21
4            30158   712630100 2008-10-27
...            ...         ...        ...
21621        44318   712841600 2014-12-03
21622        44322   712841600 2014-12-03
21623        42829   712847200 2014-03-05
21624        43547   712847200 2014-06-26
21625        42830   712847200 2014-03-05
```

Comment: You maybe want to look at the datetime module. You can then create date objects and you can perform arithmetic on date objects to check for time differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is

```
data = data.sort_values(by=['CustomerID', 'CreateDate'], ignore_index=True)

data['DaysFromPrevCustOrder'] = np.where(
    data['CustomerID'].shift(1) == data['CustomerID'],
    (data['CreateDate'] - data['CreateDate'].shift(1)).dt.days,np.nan)
```

** ## output ## **

```
       CustomerID CreateDate  OrderNumber  DaysFromPrevCustOrder
0       712013005 2008-02-13        28327                    NaN
1       712013005 2008-02-13        28327                    0.0
2       712013005 2008-02-13        28327                    0.0
3       712013005 2009-03-22        31051                  403.0
4       712013005 2009-03-22        31051                    0.0
...           ...        ...          ...                    ...
21621   712970100 2009-06-23        31662                    9.0
21622   712970100 2010-04-08        33420                  289.0
21623   712970100 2011-01-06        35184                  273.0
21624   712970100 2012-05-28        38712                  508.0
21625  7122973100 2008-09-28        30020                    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first convert your `CreateDate` column to `datetime` format:

```
df['CreateDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CreateDate'])
```

Then, you can find the location of the same `CustomerID` using the `.loc` method:

```
customer_ID = df.loc[df['CustomerID'] == '1111']
```

Finally, you can compute the difference days between two row:

```
abs((customer_ID['CreateDate'].loc[0] - customer_ID['CreateDate'][1]).days)
```

The `abs` is for ensuring to return the positive value.

Comment: i need do it for every costumerID?!

Answer (score 0):

As @Mohammadreza Riahi said, it would be best if you convert your CreateDate column to datetime format (but save the old date):

```
df['CreateDate_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CreateDate'])
```

(At this point, it's recommended to confirm the dates were parsed correctly).

Then I would order by customer id and date:

```
df = df.sort_values([CustomerID,CreateDate_dt])
```

Then add this column:

```
df['date_diff'] = np.where(df['CustomerID']==df['CustomerID'].shift(),
                          df['CreateDate_dt'] df['CreateDate_dt'].shift(),
                          np.nan)
```

The cool thing here is that there's NaN next to the first order of the customer and values in days between all the rest.

if you want days in INT:

```
df['date_diff_days']=df['date_diff'].astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

Now you can do this for example:

```
df.groupby('CustomerID').agg(purchases=('OrderNumber', 'nunique'),
                             first_purchase=('CreateDate_dt', 'min'),
                             mean_days_between_purchases=('date_diff_days', 'mean'))
```

Comment: what missing here 
 df['CreateDate_dt'] df['CreateDate_dt'].shift(),
+,-, , ?